import SentenceTransformer
in a Kaggle Notebook, https://www.kaggle.com/code/lucamassaron/data-science-ai-assistant-with-gemma-2b-it , I'm trying to execute:
 from sentence_transformers  import SentenceTransformer

"but get the following error, which I believe is due to a mis-match between tensorflow 2.18.0 in the environment and tf_keras which the code expects.
Here is the error message:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1535, in > _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
  1534 try:> -> 1535     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1536 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py:38
     37 from . import DataCollatorWithPadding, DefaultDataCollator
---> 38 from .activations_tf import get_tf_activation
     39 from .configuration_utils import PretrainedConfig

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/activations_tf.py:22
     21 try:
---> 22     import tf_keras as keras
     23 except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/__init__.py:3
      1 """AUTOGENERATED. DO NOT EDIT."""
----> 3 from tf_keras import __internal__
      4 from tf_keras import activations

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/__internal__/__init__.py:6
      5 from tf_keras.__internal__ import losses
----> 6 from tf_keras.__internal__ import models
      7 from tf_keras.__internal__ import optimizers

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/__internal__/models/__init__.py:3
      1 """AUTOGENERATED. DO NOT EDIT."""
----> 3 from tf_keras.src.models.cloning import clone_and_build_model
      4 from tf_keras.src.models.cloning import in_place_subclassed_model_state_restoration

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/src/__init__.py:21
     15 """Implementation of the TF-Keras API, the high-level API of TensorFlow.
     16 
     17 Detailed documentation and user guides are available at
     18 [keras.io](https://keras.io).
     19 """
---> 21 from tf_keras.src import applications
     22 from tf_keras.src import distribute

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/src/applications/__init__.py:41
     40 from tf_keras.src.applications.efficientnet_v2 import EfficientNetV2S
---> 41 from tf_keras.src.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
     42 from tf_keras.src.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf_keras/src/applications/inception_resnet_v2.py:324
    321     return x
--> 324 @keras.utils.register_keras_serializable()
    325 class CustomScaleLayer(keras_layers.Layer):
    326     def __init__(self, scale, **kwargs):

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tf_keras.src' has no attribute 'utils' (most likely due to a circular import)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1535, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1534 try:
-> 1535     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1536 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/integrations/integration_utils.py:34
     32 import packaging.version
---> 34 from .. import PreTrainedModel, TFPreTrainedModel
     35 from .. import __version__ as version

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1075, in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_, recursive)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1525, in _LazyModule.__getattr__(self, name)
   1524 elif name in self._class_to_module.keys():
-> 1525     module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
   1526     value = getattr(module, name)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1537, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1536 except Exception as e:
-> 1537     raise RuntimeError(
   1538         f"Failed to import {self.__name__}.{module_name} because of the following error (look up to see its"
   1539         f" traceback):\n{e}"
   1540     ) from e

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.modeling_tf_utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
partially initialized module 'tf_keras.src' has no attribute 'utils' (most likely due to a circular import)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 from sentence_transformers  import SentenceTransformer

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentence_transformers/__init__.py:14
      7 import os
      9 from sentence_transformers.backend import (
     10     export_dynamic_quantized_onnx_model,
     11     export_optimized_onnx_model,
     12     export_static_quantized_openvino_model,
     13 )
---> 14 from sentence_transformers.cross_encoder.CrossEncoder import CrossEncoder
     15 from sentence_transformers.datasets import ParallelSentencesDataset, SentencesDataset
     16 from sentence_transformers.LoggingHandler import LoggingHandler

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentence_transformers/cross_encoder/__init__.py:3
      1 from __future__ import annotations
----> 3 from .CrossEncoder import CrossEncoder
      5 __all__ = ["CrossEncoder"]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentence_transformers/cross_encoder/CrossEncoder.py:20
     18 from sentence_transformers.evaluation.SentenceEvaluator import SentenceEvaluator
     19 from sentence_transformers.readers import InputExample
---> 20 from sentence_transformers.SentenceTransformer import SentenceTransformer
     21 from sentence_transformers.util import fullname, get_device_name, import_from_string
     23 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py:33
     30 from transformers import is_torch_npu_available
     31 from transformers.dynamic_module_utils import get_class_from_dynamic_module, get_relative_import_files
---> 33 from sentence_transformers.model_card import SentenceTransformerModelCardData, generate_model_card
     34 from sentence_transformers.similarity_functions import SimilarityFunction
     36 from . import __MODEL_HUB_ORGANIZATION__, __version__

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentence_transformers/model_card.py:25
     23 from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
     24 from transformers import TrainerCallback
---> 25 from transformers.integrations import CodeCarbonCallback
     26 from transformers.modelcard import make_markdown_table
     27 from transformers.trainer_callback import TrainerControl, TrainerState

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1075, in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_, recursive)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1525, in _LazyModule.__getattr__(self, name)
   1523     value = self._get_module(name)
   1524 elif name in self._class_to_module.keys():
-> 1525     module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
   1526     value = getattr(module, name)
   1527 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1537, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1535     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1536 except Exception as e:
-> 1537     raise RuntimeError(
   1538         f"Failed to import {self.__name__}.{module_name} because of the following error (look up to see its"
   1539         f" traceback):\n{e}"
   1540     ) from e

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.integrations.integration_utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import transformers.modeling_tf_utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
partially initialized module 'tf_keras.src' has no attribute 'utils' (most likely due to a circular import)

